# mysqldump not exporting foreign key columns as foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    type INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES another_table(id)
);
```

when I run this command:

```
mysqldump --opt -f -h localhost -u root mydatabase> mydatabase.sql
```

on the file "mydatabase.sql", it creates the table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

as you can see, the "type" column is not a FOREIGN KEY that REFERENCES to another_table(id).

**Is there a way to export FK columns as FK?**

Version is 5.7.17

Comment: Check to see if the dump file has an `ALTER TABLE` command to add the FK.

Comment: Also are you InnoDB?  I seem to recall MyISAM not including foreign keys in the dump as a policy for some reason ..

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with 5.7.37.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the reply, no there isnt' any alter table that set a foreign key (I also searched in the whole file for the key "foreign" but 0 results)

Comment: @Zak thank you for the reply, the tables were MyISAM, but recently I converted them to InnoDB. I edited the post and put the rest of the row
`ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: Did you add the foreign key after converting? MYISAM ignores constraints when you create the table.

Comment: @Barmar yes, when I created the db (so the FOREIGN KEY columns), tables were MYISAM, recently I converted them to InnoDB

Comment: If you created them as MYISAM, then the foreign keys were ignored. Converting to InnoDB doesn't add them.

Comment: @Barmar yes it was the problem.
`ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES another_table(id); `
Now it works, in exported file, it create this table:

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `another_table` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

the only thing that I don't understand is: why does it call it "products_ibfk_1"?

Comment: If you don't give a name to the foreign key, MySQL creates a default name.